How can I run a php file outside symfony?
I'm encountering an issue while working on a Symfony project with an Nginx server. I'm unable to access a PHP file located outside of the project directory. Specifically, I'm trying to access a file named info.php, but I consistently receive a 404 Not Found error.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain;
    root mypublicdir/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    location = /info.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

I've attempted to access the file using the domain (mydomain/info.php), but I continue to encounter the 404 Not Found error.

Did you try to move the second location rule above the first? Also, I hope you're not using PHP 7.3 on any production system, as this is horribly outdated

I try it now but it doest work.
